# How to calculate a rate of change per year in a data frame with multiple sites and discontinuous years?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, dplyr

I have a database that looks like the next example:

| site | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| site_1 | 2000 | 10 |
| site_1 | 2001 | 15 |
| site_1 | 2004 | 23 |
| site_1 | 2006 | 20 |
| site_2 | 2001 | 9 |
| site_2 | 2002 | 9 |
| site_2 | 2007 | 15 |
| site_2 | 2008 | 16 |
| site_2 | 2010 | 17 |

I am using the next function to calculate the rate of change of the 'value' of each 'site':

```
rate <- function(x, n=1) {
c(rep(NA, n), diff(x, n))
}
```

And then I create a new column within my data frame to collect the results from that function:

```
df$rate_change <- ave(df$value, factor(df$site), FUN= rate)
```

However, I am interested in calculating a rate of change per year (final value - initial value / years) and the previous function does not consider the number of years between values. For example, the rate of change for "site_1" between 2000 and 2001 is an increase of 5 ((15 - 10)/ 1 year = 5), and between 2001 and 2004 has to be ((23 - 15)/ 3 years = 2.66).

As you can see I am using a function, but I am aware I can do it in different ways like using loops or dplyr package.

Any thoughts will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Look at `lag` and `lead` in the `dplyr` package.  There's no need to use loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(rate = c(0, diff(value)) / c(0, diff(year)), .by = site)
    site year value      rate
1 site_1 2000    10       NaN
2 site_1 2001    15  5.000000
3 site_1 2004    23  2.666667
4 site_1 2006    20 -1.500000
5 site_2 2001     9       NaN
6 site_2 2002     9  0.000000
7 site_2 2007    15  1.200000
8 site_2 2008    16  1.000000
9 site_2 2010    17  0.500000
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(site = c("site_1", "site_1", "site_1", "site_1", 
"site_2", "site_2", "site_2", "site_2", "site_2"), year = c(2000L, 
2001L, 2004L, 2006L, 2001L, 2002L, 2007L, 2008L, 2010L), value = c(10L, 
15L, 23L, 20L, 9L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```